# How do I total all values with the same date and plot it using pandas and seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I am attempting to replicate some GitHub charts across multiple repositories. I have a dataframe that holds the data I'm looking to graph that looks like this, named `stats`:

```
Dev     Commits     Repository  Date
Dev1    2           Repo1       2020-01-03
Dev2    1           Repo1       2020-01-03
Dev1    1           Repo1       2020-01-04
...
Dev3    4           Repo1       2020-10-31
Dev1    1           Repo1       2020-10-31
Dev1    1           Repo2       2020-01-02
Dev2    5           Repo2       2020-01-03
...
```

I am using seaborn to plot these numbers like so:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))
sns.lineplot(
        x="Date",
        y="Commits",
        ci=None,
        data=stats
).set_title('Commits')
```

This produces a nice line graph, but after looking at it I realized it's not correct. My dataframe is sorted by repository then date (and artifact of how I pulled the data from `git log`). It is only graphing `Repo1`, because it spans the entire year. Other repositories are not being added to the `Commits` column.

How can I graph total commits, across all repositories, through out the year? Some repositories will have multiple developers committing code on the same date on the same repository, those should be added together. Others will have commits on dates when other repositories don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to have a line plot with the commits across the dates in your dataframe. You can do this:

```
commits = stats.groupby(['Repository', 'Date']).sum()
```

Plot total commits:

```
sns.lineplot(data=commits.sort_values(by='Date',
                                      ascending=True),
                                      x='Date',
                                      y='Commits').set_title('Commits')
```

[image: total]

Plot total commits per repository:

```
sns.lineplot(data=commits.sort_values(by='Date',
                                      ascending=True),
                                      x='Date',
                                      y='Commits',
                                      hue='Repository').set_title('Commits')
```

[image: repo]